# How to refactor this kind of code to fix codeclimate duplication report?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, code-climate

I use react & flux to develop my frontend web app:

So I define the constants like this:

**/js/constants/AppConstants.js**

```
const KeyMirror = require('keymirror');

module.exports = {
  PayloadSources: KeyMirror({
    SERVER_ACTION: null,
    VIEW_ACTION: null
  })
};
```

**/js/constants/ProductConstants.js**

```
const KeyMirror = require('keymirror');

module.exports = {
  ActionTypes: KeyMirror({
    GET_PRODUCT: null,
    UPDATE_PRODUCT: null,
  })
};
```

This totally works and is correct, then I push these codes to Github (with Codeclimate integration).

Codeclimate says:

```
Similar code found in 1 other location (mass = 54)
const KeyMirror = require('keymirror');
```

Obviously, we see that this line `const KeyMirror = require('keymirror')` was defined in 2 different files, and Codeclimate thinks this should be changed. But I was thinking, this is just a statement to import the library.

How do you think? How should I need to refactor this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you, this is just a statement to import some other code, and it needs to be there whenever you want to use the functionality. So, the only *possible* refactoring would be to merge the two files `AppConstants` and `ProductConstants`. But this is probably not a good refactoring because it sounds like a good idea to separate the app constants and the product constants.

I would rather raise an issue with codeclimate than try to refactor this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have control over your codeclimate settings for your repo, but you can change the mass threshold in your `.codeclimate.yml`. I've been experimenting with different thresholds with our React/Redux application and currently have ours set to 65, but we might bump that up to around 75.

```
---
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    config:
      languages:
        javascript:
          mass_threshold: 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Yo Wakita, you can set the duplication threshold like this now in `.codeclimate.yml`:

checks:
identical-code:
config:
threshold: 50
similar-code:
config:
threshold: 75

See: https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication

Hope it helps anyone